# How to set previewLayer (camera view) to fill view

Tags: avfoundation, swift4, ios11

i have a view and would like the camera to display in the whole view in the grey area. currently it only display, shown in the black area.

[current situation faced]

[image]

i am using `xcode`, `swift 4`, for `iOS 11`.

> May I know how to make my camera view fill the grey part?

currently for my preview layer i did:

`previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
self.previewLayer.frame = self.camView.layer.bounds
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
self.camView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)`

I have also set constraint for bottom, left, right to be 0. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Copy/Past your code, so we can identify your problem.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati edited

Answer (score 1):

Working fine in my case

```
previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller, set size on `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    previewLayer.frame = camView.bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`videoPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame`

This simple line of code worked for me.